# Outbounds Image Pieces in PageCurl Transition on UIPageViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uipageviewcontroller

I have an application in which I have implemented the system transitions between views UIPageViewController offers. The problem I have is that in each view images placed indicating the Frame where they have to be affixed. If this frame outside the screen, when I make the transition to pass page, the pieces of the images protruding frames page are shown. I know the best way for do this is edit the image erasing this piece, but the problem is that this images with I have the problem, are dynamically set in place for each size of screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to this is setting view.clipsToBounds = true.